# In a flexbox grid, how do I prevent the first row from pushing down the second?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex design that looks kinda like this:

```css
.columns {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: block;
}

.column.is-8 {
   flex: none;
   width: 66.66667%;
}

.column.is-4 {
    flex: none;
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
    height: 400px;
}
.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
    height: 800px;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8 box-1">
      Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="column is-4 box-2">
      Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="column is-8 box-3">
      Box 3
  </div>
</div>
<!-- on desktop: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
<!-- on mobile: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
```

How can I prevent box 2 from pushing down box 3? So it would look like this:

[image]

### Update

I would like to add that on mobile, the boxes should be in the same order (e.g. 1, 2 then 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this, using the `grid` layout. It lets you make grids (surprise, surprise) and it gives you more control over everything inside it. So something like this:

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.column {
  display: block;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8 box-1">
      Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="column is-4 box-2">
      Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="column is-8 box-3">
      Box 3
  </div>
</div>
<!-- on desktop: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
<!-- on mobile: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
```

Edit: to make it responsive, you can quite easily pop this at the end of your css:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .columns {
        display: block;
  }
}
```

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.column {
  display: block;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .columns {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8 box-1">
      Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="column is-4 box-2">
      Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="column is-8 box-3">
      Box 3
  </div>
</div>
<!-- on desktop: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
<!-- on mobile: box 1, 2 and 3 -->
```

Comment: I see, interesting. I thought about grid too, but was hoping that it was possible with flex. Anyhow, how would you make box 1, 2 and 3 then be 100% on mobile?

Comment: Just edited post.

Comment: For second issue, I saw a big issue with flex as it doesn't support rows :( there might be a really long, long workaround but I'm not sure :(

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution, however, I am getting "Invalid Property Value" for `grid-template-columns: 2fr / 1fr;`

Comment: Ah, it had to be `grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;`

Comment: let me update my post again :) don't forget that you can always accept an answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223751/discussion-between-foobar-and-corn-on-the-cob).

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup your template a bit differently as box 1 and 3 is in the same column. You can achieve the desired layout by wrapping box 1 and 3 in a div.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
}

.column.is-8 {
  width: 66.66667%;
}

.column.is-4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}


.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 800px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
  <div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8">
    <div class="box-1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box-3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-4">
    <div class="box-2">Box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Abdallah Ajjawi, thanks for your answer. The only issue with this approach is that I would like the order (Box 1, 2, 3) to be the same on mobile. With your approach it would be 1,3, 2 on mobile

Answer (score 3):

here is another possibility with `grid` and `auto-fit` *(see comment in CSS for the setting)*

Snippet to run in full page and resize to see behavior.

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  /*Below : 400px for minmax  is more than a third  of 1000px width of the container
  to draw at most 2 columns */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column {
  border: solid;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100px;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8 box-1">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="column is-4 box-2">
    Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="column is-8 box-3">
    Box 3
  </div>
</div>
```